# Writing printf(@"") with multiple line string

Tags: c, printf, codeblocks

Is it possible to write something like this:

```
printf(@"

-
-
-
-
");
```

I can do it in C#, but can't in C. It gives me an error in CodeBlocks. Am I allowed to do such ?

Error message: *error: stray '@' in program.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line continuation with `\` at the end of the line.

```
printf("\
\
-\
-\
-\
-\
");
```

Answer (score 2):

No. That syntax doesn't exist in C.

If you want a multiple-line string, write it as multiple double-quoted strings with no other tokens in between them. They will be combined.

```
printf(
    "some string"
    "more of the string"
    "even more of the string"
);
```

(You will, of course, need to add a `\n` at the end of each line if that's what you want.)

Answer (score 2):

No that's not a syntax that C understands, C doesn't have raw literals. 
You can use \ as the last character to continue on the next line:

```
   const char *str = "hello\n\
world";
```

Also, consecutive string literals will be concatenated. So you can do e.g.

```
const char *str = "Hello\n"
"world\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

C#'s verbatim strings are not available in C. If you have some characters to escape, like " or \, escape them with '\', there is no there option in this language.

If you want to embed multiple lines in a string literal, you can either insert \n at the appropriate location in your string, or escape the return character as well:

```
printf("Here's\
       a multiline\
       string litteral");
```

Answer (score 1):

String literals in C may not contain newlines.  You have two workarounds:

1. Use implicit string concatenation (done by the compiler).

   ```
   printf("The quick brown"
          " fox jumps over"
          " the sleazy dog.");
   ```
2. Escape the newline by placing a backslash in front of it.

   ```
   printf("The quick brown\
    fox jumps over\
    the sleazy dog.");
   ```

Personally, I prefer the first form since the second looks ugly (my opinion) and forces you to ruin your code indentation.

In either case, the string will *simply not contain* the newlines.  So if you really meant for them to be there, you'll have to add them via `\n`.